# Localhost subdomain on XP Pro IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-xp, localhost

Is there a way to setup subdomains udner Xp Pro IIS for something like test.localhost

Can it be done via IIS or the hosts file?  Need to do a tets on a site that uses pathign back to the root so having the site ina virtual directory like localhost/test causes issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're probably well aware that out of the box IIS 5.1 only supports one web site. What you can do is use the `adsutil.vbs` tool to create a second site in IIS 5.1 and configure it to use that.

The following article explains the process:

> [IIS: Creating Multiple Web Sites within IIS on Windows 2000 and Windows XP Professional](http://www.xoc.net/works/tips/multiple-iis-sites-professional.asp)

There's even a GUI widget to make life easy:

> http://www.firstserved.net/support/downloads

So in a nutshell:

1. Create a second site using one of
   the methods above (set the IP
   address to your machine's primary IP
   address)
2. Add a host header for
   `test.localhost` domain to the new
   site
3. Edit the HOSTS and add an entry for
   `test.localhost` pointing at the IP
   address above

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to just switch the document root of the lone site you already have to the different folder with the target site. Then you can switch it back when done.

If you are building stuff in virtual directories off the root, this shouldn't even effect any ongoing projects.

I seem to recall there was a tool which did this for you, but I've forgotten it's name and coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new website in IIS. The host header value should be your subdomain like "sub.localhost", and then add the domain to your hosts file.

Comment: Ah my bad. I was thinking that was only a limitation on Home.

Comment: XP home doesn't even have IIS . . .

Answer (score -1):

open with notepad the file c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc

and add this line:

```
 127.0.0.1 mysuper-site.com.net.blabla
```

Then browse to this site: http://mysuper-site.com.net.blabla

Comment: That won't help if the web server isn't set up to recieve the subdomain request.

Comment: Yes how would I map that to the subdomain?

Comment: wait... isn't IIS listning on 127.0.0.1? When I do this setup in apache, the application is responsible for determinating the domain (well, apache can do this on itself as well...)